# Return inline comment to a new line

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to parse a code block line-by line. Is there a way to grab in-line comments and return it to the next line? I would imagine using regex, but I am having trouble coming up with the expression. 
Example:

```
if(foo) { //Executes bar function
  bar();
}
```

will be

```
if(foo) { 
  //Executes bar function
  bar();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "trying to parse a code block" - why aren't you using one of the existing JS parsers? And why "line by line"?

Comment: To clarify -- My use case is reading an unformatted text file and and then formatting it correctly to a set of standards.

Comment: Unless you use a JS parser as @Bergi says, I wish you good luck with code like this: `var x = "if (foo) { // Comment }";`

Comment: @BackbonePrincess: Don't reinvent the wheel. What you want to build is called a "prettifier" or "beautifier". Many such libaries do already exist for JS, including custom rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JavaScript, could do something like turn all your code into a string and `/(\/\/.+$)/g` to capture inline comments and then use replace like:

```
 stringVar.replace(/(\/\/.+$)/, '\n\t $1 \n').
```

If you have a text editor or IDE with regex support, you could use the above `.replace` pattern for the `find` and `replace` options respectively.

Comment: I think I'm still using the first part incorrectly, but the replace regex pattern actually fixed my bug of indenting. So I will mark this checked! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

To match all single line - comments that are not in an otherwise empty line, you could use following regex:

`/^.*\S+.*(\/\/.*$)/mg`

https://regex101.com/r/fU5lO4/1

example

```
console.log("hello"); // this comment will be matched
// this comment won't be matched
         // this comment won't be matched
```

You could replace the found comment with a newline + itself. (And maybe add some whitespaces?)

example

```
 yourText.replace(/^(.*\S+.*)(\/\/.*$)/mg, '$1\n $2' );
```